# Galois group isomorphic to $\mathfrak{S}_5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ an irreducible polynomial of degree $5$ and with splitting field $K \supset \mathbb{Q}$. If $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})$ are subfields of $K$,is possible that $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})\approx \mathfrak{S}_5$?.

I think that no! I think it has something to do with the fact that there is only subgrup $G$ the ordr $10$ of $\mathfrak{S}_5$. but I can not solve this problem! Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hint:  What do you know about the quotients of $\mathfrak{S}_5$?

Comment: A quadratic extension corresponds to an index two subgroup of the Galois group. How many index two subgroups are there in $\mathfrak{S}_5$?